# Jenkins deploy Angular 2+ Project To Tomcat

Tags: angular, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, tomcat9

I'm new to Jenkins and I'm trying to Build and deploy My angular project to Tomcat using Jenkins. I cannot find any Jenkins Job Configuration.

I found some useful [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbUqgS82d48)

but this will run `npm install` and `npm run build` and creates dist folder with files

I'm stuck in deployment.

[image]

Comment: Let me understand it better. You have an angular project. You would like to build it and deploy it to a server? Where is that server and Which operating system the Jenkins runs on? Where is your project source? is it in Github or something like that ?

Comment: @RamKamath, yes.  currently I'm using windows OS (localhost) and project is in Git, and also I need this configuration  to use In Linux environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your intention is to automate the deploy step**

Jenkins is designed to work as a centralised CD server which can deliver artefact to repository or a server. In your case, I assume you are running the Jenkins on same machine where you are doing development. That is technical feasible setup. But, that is not how it is intended to be used. For you a single sh or batch script would work instead of a whole Jenkins server if your intention is to put reusable commands in one place. In that case, yes you would just copy the content to the webapp or similar directory.

**If your intention is to make use of the continuous delivery**
Jenkins is a right tool. 
The "ideal" flow is **dev machine => SCM => CI => STAGING/PRD**

All four of them run on different server.

This is how you can configure and use Jenkins.

- Create a [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#steps) and add it to the repository and commit it.
- Configure Jenkins by adding a n**ew Task -> Muti-branch Pipeline -> Select SCM as your git repository -> Select the branches you want to build -> Scan repository now**

Begin with the below Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
  stage("Build Project") {
      script {
              bat "npm install"
              bat "npm run build"
            }
   }
  stage("deploy"){
     script {
             bat "<Your deploy command>"
          }
    }
}
post {
  always{
     deleteDir()   
  }
}
}
```

The advantage of using such a Jenkins file is, you can put it in scm and track the changes. If you have a New Jenkins, you can simply reconfigure the Job and all your pipeline stages can be visualised.

For Linux, replace `bat` with `sh`.

For more information please check the official guide https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#pipeline-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Add the PowerShell step or Shell Script step Depending on Build machine OS. Add command to copy all these files under dist/ (eg. copy my-angular ) and paste them in /angular folder under /webapps folder

Hit: localhost:8080/my-angular/index.html

**If Required you can restart the tomcat server**

Comment: @ Shubham Gorlewar, Thanks for the answer. I have try this answer and its works fine, But I need to know if there are any better solution than that